# How can I append a sadgan[1] to my test string?

Tags: objective-c

I have a 
const char *sadgan[4]={"yeksad" ,"devist","sisad","chaharsad","pansad"};
How can I append a sadgan[1] to test in objective c?

```
    NSString *myString =@"";
    NSString *test = [myString stringByAppendingString:sadgan[1]];
    NSLog(@"% ? " ,test);
```

I want to write yeksad o devist o sisad o ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char*` and `NSString` are not converted to each other automatically. If you use Objective-C, use `NSString` unless some library you use forces you otherwise. `"abc"` is a `char*`, `@"abc"` is an `NSString`.

```
NSArray* sagdan=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"yeksad",@"devist",@"sisad",@"chaharsad",@"pansad",nil];
NSString *test = [myString stringByAppendingString:[sagdan objectAtIndex:4]];
```

will do the job.

By the way, what's the language you used? dev for 2, chahar for 4 and pan for 5 sound like an Indo-European language...

Comment: thank you , i'm beginner in objective c and it's my first source code :)
it's persian.
yeksad=100 devist=200 ,...
yek=1 do=2 se=3 chahar=4...

Answer (score 1):

Convert a C Sting to an NSString:

```
NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cString];
```

and then append.

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic for Objective-C but on-topic for C:

*sadgan[4]={"yeksad" ,"devist","sisad","chaharsad","pansad"};

I don’t know this language, but I can’t help: 1: yeksad, 2: devist, 3: sisad, 4: chaharsad, 5: pansad. Which one do you think will be droped by the array, capable holding 4 values?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

@ objective Interested person:

in c:

```
  const char * array_1[4]={"one","two","tree","four","five"};
  printf("%s",array_1[4]) //output= five
```

in objective_c:`

```
 NSString *mystring=@"";

 NSArray* array_1=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"tree",@"four",@"five",nil];

 NSString *test = [mystring stringByAppendingString:[array_1 objectAtIndex:4]];  

 NSLog(@"%@",test);     //output =five
```

Comment: your declaration of `const char * array_1[4]` is wrong.  It should be `[5]`.

Comment: why?? in c array rang is (0 .. 4 )= 5

Answer (score 0):

@aden: Sure, the array data is placed in the heap. This is done in the usual way, so you can acess it. But it is not secure: it depends on the way, the compiler is actually handling such things. And: what if the array is not located on the heap? Maybe on the stack? Yes, in most cases this will be a bad idea, but it is still an idea.

A real bad idea is the way to think “it’s just working, so don’t worry about it”. Don’t make unneccessary assumptions.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

@aden: “why?? in c array rang is (0 .. 4 )= 5” — looks as you should have a few lessons in C first? `something array[value];` is reserving memory space. Space for *value* “somethings”. You just know, the index starts with 0. So just try out: if the first element is called 0, what is the index for the last one if there are *value* elements?

Greetings